# unbind click (i.e. stop the element from forwarding the user to the href value) jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

What i want to do is stop the clickable link from forwarding the user to the href value as i am calling the value via .load().

Here is my code;

```
$('#prac_slider li a').click(function(){
    var $permalink = $('#prac_slider li a').attr('href');
    $('div#abc').load($permalink + ' #loadMe');
});
```

i have tried to add `.unbind('click', variable);` to the element and loading my above code via a variable but it still seems to forward the user.

Everything else works, it loads the data into #abc but it then forwards the user to the href itself.

How would i disable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `return false`:

```
$('#prac_slider li a').click(function(){
    var $permalink = $('#prac_slider li a').attr('href');
    $('div#abc').load($permalink + ' #loadMe');
    return false;
});
```

This prevents the default action from being performed, in the case of an `a` it prevents the link being followed, in the case of a checkbox it prevents un/checking of the box.

You could, similarly, use `event.preventDefault()`:

```
$('#prac_slider li a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var $permalink = $('#prac_slider li a').attr('href');
    $('div#abc').load($permalink + ' #loadMe');
});
```

As pointed out by T.J. Crowder, in the comments below, `event.preventDefault()` and `return false` are **not** equivalent: `return false` is `event.preventDefault` *and* `event.stopPropagation()` (the latter of which prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree).

Reference:

- [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).
- [`event.stopPropagation().`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)
- The accepted answer, from Karim79, in the Stack Overflow question: [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/javascript-event-preventdefault-vs-return-false/1357151#1357151)

Comment: man you are a legend, completely forgot about that ! +1 and will mark within 10 mins or so :)  Thanks David

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, indeed; that's mainly why I pointed Xavier to Karim79's answer on the linked question. Though, to be fair, I probably should've added that to the answer... **Now edited-in**